# Discrepancy in the definition of a module over a group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group. A **G-module M** is defined as an abelian group on which $G$ acts through the map
$ G \times M \to M$
where
$ (g, m) \mapsto g \cdot m$
This action satisfies
$g \cdot (m + m') = g \cdot m + g \cdot m', 
\forall m, m' \in M$.

When $G$ is a Galois group, a **G-module M** is described as an abelian group on which $G$ acts continuously, respecting the Krull topology on $G$ and the discrete topology on $M$.

Are these two definitions compatible? In particular, if $G$ acts continuously on $M$, does it necessarily imply that the action
$G \times M \to M,
(g, m) \mapsto g \cdot m$
satisfies
$g \cdot (m + m') = g \cdot m + g \cdot m' , 
\forall m, m' \in M$?

Comment: The algebraic definitions are equal for both. But in the second, a topology is required in addition, also for the (infinite) Galois group, so that the action is continuous. See Milne's lecture notes on galois cohomology.

Comment: In the second definition, "acts" implicitly means "by linear transformations," so it includes the additivity axiom. It should be "continuous $G$-module." In the first definition there aren't any topologies (or if you prefer the topologies are all discrete).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a $G$-module for a profinite group is as follows.

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a profinite group. An abelian group $M$ is called a *continuous* (or discrete) $G$-module, if it is a $G$-module in the usual sense, and in addition the action $G\times M\rightarrow M$ is *continuous* when $M$ is endowed with the discrete topology, and $G\times M$ with the product topology.

So in particular, $g(m+m')=gm+gm'$ already holds.

Not every $G$-module $M$ is continuous. Consider the Galois extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\Bbb N})/\Bbb Q$ with Galois group $G$. Then
$$
M=\prod_p\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})
$$
is a $G$-module, which is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your intriguing example. Could you tell me which open set in $M$ is not open under the pullback?

Comment: If $M$ is continuous, then $G\times \{m\}\rightarrow M$ is continuous and any $m\in M$ has only finitely many images under the action of $G$. This is not true, take for example $m=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\ldots)$, which has infinitely many images.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm probably stuck on some fundamental aspects. Galois group can be regarded as inverse limit of finite groups, why is your Galois group $G$ is not pro finite ?

Comment: "My" Galois group is profinite, as inverse limit of the Galois groups of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1},\ldots,\sqrt{n})/\Bbb Q$, i.e., $G=\varprojlim_n {\rm Gal}( \Bbb Q(\sqrt{1},\ldots,\sqrt{n})/\Bbb Q)$.